# Disable Flash Player in Chrome via Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, google-chrome, flash

How would I disable the Flash player in Google Chrome browsers for my 50 AD computers via group policy or script in 2008 R2?

I have tried a couple of applications, PDQDeploy_6 among them, but this software is not suitable for my task.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned PDQ Deploy. There is a package available in the Package Library which does just what you are asking for. It is called "Google Chrome - Disable Flash".

Also, if you use Active Directory you can use the Chrome ADMX templates to enforce this (and just about anything else Chrome wise).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You can use the [`DisabledPlugins`](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DisabledPlugins) policy.

For Linux, append the attribute

```
DisabledPlugins: ["Shockwave Flash"]
```

to the `/etc/chromium/policies/managed/any_name.json` file, or create a new JSON object containing only this attribute.

If you eschew deprecated policy settings, have a look at
[`DefaultPluginsSetting`](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DefaultPluginsSetting), but that either blocks all or allows all.

For Windows, have a look at https://www.chromium.org/administrators/windows-quick-start. In short, the following steps should help

1. download [the MSI](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?msi=true)
2. download [the ADM[x] template](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates)
3. configure settings for your network (see link above, depending on whether ADM or ADMX is used
4. push to network

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps modify the Application shortcut via GPMC and add the "--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash" switch so that Chrome launches without the bundled Flash player.

I hope [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753580.aspx) article helps.

Comment: Could u write some detailed steps how to modify application via GPM ? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have access to a system that I can test this on right now. Will update if I am able to get my hands on one.